# Devise - send authenticated user to www.website.com/profile/1 (there profile page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise and I need for an authenticated user to land on the profile page for that user.

the url path looks like this...www.website.com/profile/1

CURRENTLY the authenticated user lands here

www.website.com/

Here is a snippet from my routes.rb file of the offending code.

```
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index' # TODO direct to profile page
  end
```

How do I change the above so the user is directed to ...www.website.com/profile/1

Note: here is the output for rake routes for profile

```
                   profiles GET        /profiles(.:format)                           profiles#index
                            POST       /profiles(.:format)                           profiles#create
                new_profile GET        /profiles/new(.:format)                       profiles#new
               edit_profile GET        /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)                  profiles#edit
                    profile GET        /profiles/:id(.:format)                       profiles#show
                            PUT        /profiles/:id(.:format)                       profiles#update
                            DELETE     /profiles/:id(.:format)                       profiles#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the Devise method `after_sign_in_path_for`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  profile_path(resource.profile)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, 4hrs I spent on this. Yours was the only direct answer. And it works!